# Creation dates wrong on site directory

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-exchange

The "Created *X* months ago" text appears to be wrong on the [Site Directory](https://stackexchange.com/sites?expand=true#sharepoint).

[image: Site dates]

Comment: The SharePoint site was originally an SE 1.0 Site, imported into the network, so the creation date is correct, there's content that far back.

Comment: @Nick There should be content further much back than that (not showing in the site). I should have mentioned there are other sites that had this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed.  We now show the site's private beta date to avoid any confusion.  Previously we were using the Community user's creation date to try to determine the actual creation date of the site, but for imported sites this led to some oddities.